# How to get exact position on mapview(x , y cordinates) from lat lon in mkmapkit

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, latitude-longitude

I want the exact position on mkmapkit that is x y cordinate from lat lon values .

I used the followind code

`CLLocationCoordinate2D neCoord;
    neCoord.latitude = 72.2234;
    neCoord.longitude = 23.340876;
    //Here i have passed hardcoded lat lon 
    nePoint = [map_view convertCoordinate:neCoord toPointToView:map_view];`

But i get the cordinates to be negative values.

So any idea or suggestions for the same are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're getting negative numbers because the `MKMapView` isn't showing the region where the coordinates are? If they're both negative, then the location is NW of the current displayed map region.

Comment: You aren't wrong, but you need to change the displayed map region. Then the point's coords will be positive.